# How to disable autocmd or augroup in vim?

Tags: vim

Given I have a group of commands such as:

```
augroup MyGroup
  autocmd CursorMoved * silent call MyCommandOne()
augroup END
```

I want to disable all the autocommands in MyGroup for a time and then re-enable it later.

Is there anything I can do with the group? Specifically, is there a way to disable the whole group at once? If not, what can I do to disable individual commands?

Looking at the help, I only see a few options:

- `augroup!` will delete the whole group: I don't think this is right since I will want to re-enable it again. (But maybe there's a way to easily redefine the group again?)
- `:noautocmd` will only disable the callbacks for a one-off invocation of a command. (And it disables *all* autocmds, not specified ones)
- `eventignore` addresses the event binding, not the command: it sounds like it disables all bound commands for a given event, not just one command or a group I can specify.

How is this done?

Answer (score 28):

From `:help autocmd`:

```
If you want to skip autocommands for one command, use the :noautocmd command
modifier or the 'eventignore' option.
```

From `:help :noautocmd`:

```
To disable autocommands for just one command use the ":noautocmd" command
modifier.  This will set 'eventignore' to "all" for the duration of the
following command.  Example:

    :noautocmd w fname.gz

This will write the file without triggering the autocommands defined by the
gzip plugin.
```

So it appears `:noautocmd` is what you are looking for.

In what context do you want to disable an `augroup`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I read this in the docs already. I clarified my question to (hopefully) show what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 13):

From [here](http://osdir.com/ml/editors.vim/2002-02/msg00181.html), it seems that this achieves it:

```
:augroup Foo
:autocmd BufEnter * :echo "hello"
:augroup END

...

:autocmd! Foo BufEnter *
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who doesn't have the original posters requirement of being able to restore the `augroup`, `:autocmd! <augroup name>` is the command to simply delete all `autocmd` in an `augroup`, e.g.:

```
:autocmd! MyGroup
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to temporarily disable `autocmd` globally for a given event, you can do:

```
set eventignore=CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,InsertLeave
```

...listing whichever events you want to temporarily ignore. This won't be limited to a specific `augroup` however.

To re-enable these events just reset eventignore:

```
set eventignore=""
```

Dropping this answer here in case anyone stumbles upon this question like I did but none of the other answers suffice for their situation.